# Access to query's permalinks for users with other roles/spaces

Tags: kibana, permalinks, kibana-7

Our Kibana (7.17.1) users would like to share queries (via *Discover* → *Share* → *Permalinks*) with other users that have different roles/spaces assigned. At the moment the target users get just a blank page if they use the permalink URL.

I activated [anonymous authentication](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.17/kibana-authentication.html#anonymous-authentication) to enable [Public URL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.17/reporting-getting-started.html#share-a-direct-link)s as a try, but the underlying anonymous user in turn needs role(s)/space(s) assigned and I can't add everything there since this would be against our data security policy.

I also tried [the built-in role `viewer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/built-in-roles.html#built-in-roles-viewer) for the anonymous user but this didn't work without an explicit role in addition and "*This functionality is in technical preview and may be changed or removed in a future release.*" and "*read access to any index that is not prefixed with a dot*" is also against our security policy anyway.

Is it possible somehow else to give users with different roles/spaces access to shared permalinks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an extra *Share* space and:

- assigned it to all the respective roles and
- added all the respective index patterns to it.

The only drawback is that the users have to switch to this space prior to creating a link if they'd like to share it with users of other roles/spaces.